# Backpropagation Algorithm not

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Every single derivation of the BPA I have ever seen uses particular loss functions as example. The derivative is computed with respect to the weights and then a recursive relation is found. Now while I understand every derivation, I have not been able to generalize this for an arbitrary loss function. In other words, given an arbitrary loss function, I would not be able to backpropagate errors if I don't know the exact form of it.

Is there any paper, book etc. which does the BPA in general? Is this even possible?

Comment: From the perspective of software, derivatives of arbitrary functions are usually addressed using autograd, symbolic differentiation or numeric differentiation and then applying the chain rule. From the perspective of math, you're correct that there is no one-size-fits-all solution because the gradient update will depend critically on which loss function you are using. Is this helpful, or are you asking about something else?

Comment: I understand that there is not a single solution for every costfunction, this would be trivial. But I have also not seen any derivation where I could insert the derivation of the cost function. The derivations are done from beginning on with a particular cost function.

Comment: Can you not just take the derivative of your loss with respect to your final prediction y_hat and use it as a factor when you use the chain rule, since the rest (i.e, derivative of y_hat wrt to any weights you are interested in) does not depend on the loss you are using?